# Getting an error in (C# Program for Tic Tac Toe)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

**About the Program:**

I have written a C# code for making Tic Tac Toe. It is made in windows form application (Visual studio).
while playing this game, When X or O wins, the method=> **checkForwinner()** is  called that does horizontal,vertical and diagonal check for determining winner. Variable **there_is_a_winner** is set to true and the message" winner wins is displayed". Else it checks for draw.

**Error:**

When i complied this code, it shows 0 error/warning/messages.But inspite of that, this code is not working. It is not able to determine the winner. The popup box, displaying who won/draw..never executes, other than that, this code works fine. I hope someone could help.

Thanks in advance.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    bool turn = true;//(To check turn) True means X's turn, False=Y turn
    int turn_count = 0;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void aboutToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)/*About Section*/
    {
        MessageBox.Show("This Program is of Tic Tac Toe. It was created by Me for his C# project.","Tic Tac Toe -About");
    }

    private void exitToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)/*Exit Section*/
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }

    private void button_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button b = (Button)sender;
        if(turn)
            b.Text="x";
        else
        b.Text="o";
        turn=!turn;
        b.Enabled = false;//disable the button, to prevent double entering.
        turn_count++;
    }
    private void checkForwinner()
    {
        bool there_is_a_winner= false;

        //horizontal check
        
         if ((A1.Text == A2.Text) && (A2.Text == A3.Text) && (!A1.Enabled))
            there_is_a_winner = true;//if above conditions are true, then bool variable=true.
        else if ((B1.Text == B2.Text) && (B2.Text == B3.Text) && (!B1.Enabled))
            there_is_a_winner = true;

        else if ((C1.Text == C2.Text) && (C2.Text == C3.Text) && (!C1.Enabled))
            there_is_a_winner = true;

        //Vertical Check
        else if ((A1.Text == B1.Text) && (B1.Text == C1.Text) && (!A1.Enabled))
            there_is_a_winner = true;

        else if ((A2.Text == B2.Text) && (B2.Text == C2.Text) && (!A2.Enabled))
            there_is_a_winner = true;

        else if ((A3.Text == B3.Text) && (B3.Text == C3.Text) && (!A3.Enabled))
            there_is_a_winner = true;

        //Diagonal Check
        else if ((A1.Text == B2.Text) && (B2.Text == C3.Text) && (!A1.Enabled))
            there_is_a_winner = true;

        else if ((A3.Text == B2.Text) && (B2.Text == C1.Text) && (!C1.Enabled))
            there_is_a_winner = true;

         if (there_is_a_winner)
         {
             dissableButtons();// If there is a winner call for buttons to be disbaled.

             String winner = "";
             if (turn)
                 winner = "0";
             else
                 winner = "x";
             MessageBox.Show(winner + "Wins!", "Congratulations!");
         }
        else
        {
            if (turn_count == 9)
                MessageBox.Show("Match Draw", "Result");
        }

        
    }
        private void dissableButtons()
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (Control c in Controls)
                {
                    Button b = (Button)c;
                    b.Enabled = false;//If there is a winner, disable all the buttons on the form
                }

            }
            catch { }
        }
    // New Game//Need to Reset Everything
        private void toolStripMenuItem2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            turn = true;
            turn_count = 0;
            try
            {
                foreach (Control c in Controls)
                {
                    Button b = (Button)c;
                    b.Enabled = true;
                    b.Text = "";//Initially we want blank Text

                }
            }
            catch { }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: use a debugger and step through your code. Also "it doesn't work" is too broad - please explain the input you give and the output you expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the function checkForwinner() never gets called anywhere in the program.

I expect that the button_click function puts an X or a O in the appropriate cell, so when that button is clicked, it also needs to check to see if there is a winner.  I suggest you call checkForwinner() as the last line in your button_click function so that every time it is clicked, the check is carried out.

Also, as a style note, please rename it to checkForWinner with a capital W. Also you should indent the line b.Text="o"; like this:

```
    if(turn)
        b.Text="x";
    else
        b.Text="o";
```

Having said that, I prefer to have curly braces even on one-liners so I'd prefer this:

```
    if(turn) 
    {
        b.Text="x";
    }
    else
    {
        b.Text="o";
    }
```

Even though that takes up a lot more lines, it does save you from future problems when you add another line into the "if" clause or into the "else" clause and forget to add those all-important curly braces.  It's a good habit to get into - curly braces everywhere.

Comment: Yes,  checkForwinner() never gets called anywhere in the program...that's what the problem was. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

When you ask question you have to be more specific. In this case you have do more, because I see several big mistakes in this code. I just point out few of them:

1. you should never do this:

   ```
   try 
   {
    ...
   }
   catch {}
   ```

If you do this, you "eat" the exception and you never know what happend. There is only very few cases when you need to use catch. Don't use **catch** until you know what are you doing.

Instead of that you can display any exception at application level:

in Program.cs, in method Main add :

```
static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.ThreadException += Application_ThreadException;
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomain_UnhandledException;
        Application.Run(new Form());
    }

    private static void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
          MessageBox.Show(((Exception)e.ExceptionObject).Message);      
    }

    private static void Application_ThreadException(object sender, System.Threading.ThreadExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
          MessageBox.Show(e.Exception.Message);      
    }
}
```

2. In your method **button_click** you use `if .. else ...` but check if you don't need add `{ ... }` :

   ```
   if (...) {
       code here
   }
   else {
      code here
   }
   ```
3. Use visibility qualifier **private** for private fields:

   ```
   private bool turn = true;//(To check turn) True means X's turn, False=Y turn    
   private int turn_count = 0;
   ```
4. Instead of `Application.Exit();` use method `Form.Close()`: `this.Close();`
5. If you use `if .. else if ..` block, always use final else block with exception. It will show you what you miss:

   ```
   if (...)
   {
      ...
   }
   else if (...)  
   {
      ...
   }
   else
   {
     throw new NotImplementedException("Not Implemented Yet");
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you...for the answer.